# Flutter: 'google_sign_in' pub Build failed #import <AppAuth/AppAuthCore.h>

Tags: flutter

I was having a problem with building iOS app with my project. So, I have been testing with different packages.

Apparently,

`google_sign_in` is giving me an error.

I have only added

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.6
```

If I try this on `dev channel` then I receive

Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳

```
Desktop/hey/ios/Pods/GTMAppAuth/Source/GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorizat
ion.m:26:9: fatal error: 'AppAuth/AppAuthCore.h' file not found
#import <AppAuth/AppAuthCore.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
```

And, on `stable channel`,

```
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/gi/Desktop/heey/ios/Pods/GTMAppAuth/Source/GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthoriza
    tion.m:26:9: fatal error: 'AppAuth/AppAuthCore.h' file not found
    #import <AppAuth/AppAuthCore.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is
    set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.3.99. (in target 'google_sign_in' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is
    set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.3.99. (in target 'GTMAppAuth' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is
    set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.3.99. (in target 'GoogleSignIn' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is
    set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.3.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is
    set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.3.99. (in target 'AppAuth' from project 'Pods')
```

I looked for lifting the target to 9.0 and I tried multiple solutions that I have found on here or Google but none of them working.

I have no clue what I have to do to fix this. Nothing seems to work.

---- edit

```
Flutter 1.22.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 7891006299 (9 days ago) • 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800
Engine • revision ae90085a84
Tools • Dart 2.10.4
```

Comment: What OS are you using? what version of Xcode? what version of flutter\dart?
Could you add that to your question?

Comment: Try importing firebase_core package. I think it is required when using google_sign_in as well

Comment: I edit the configuration. And, I added firebase_core and still get `fatal error:
    'AppAuth/AppAuthCore.h' file not found` error

Comment: Solved it by reinstalling macOS and everything.